# How To create the packet and send using java?

Tags: java, sockets, packet

Hi I am getting the Data from the GPS device, I want to send the response back to the Gps device by creating the packet MY packet is like this.

```
No. Field   TYPE    Length  description
1   sMark    Char   6   Flag of message (\r\n*KW\0)
2   packetLe short  2   Message Length
3   CMD  Short  2   0x8200
4   cErrorCodeChar  1   0x00OK, 0x01invalid deviceID
5   sEnd     Char   2   message end "\r\n"
```

I want Crete Packet like this by using this code.

```
InetAddress IPAddress = receivePacket.getAddress();
              String sendString = "polo";
              sendData = sendString.getBytes();
              DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, port);
              serverSocket.send(sendPacket);
```

I am trying like this.

```
 ByteArrayOutputStream bytearrypacket = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream dateoutputpacket = new DataOutputStream(bytearrypacket);
        dateoutputpacket.writeChars("\r\n*KW\0");
        dateoutputpacket.writeShort(15);
        dateoutputpacket.writeShort(82);
        dateoutputpacket.writeChar('1');
        dateoutputpacket.writeChars("\r\n");
        dateoutputpacket.flush();

        byte[] result = bytearrypacket.toByteArray();
```

Updated:

```
   ByteArrayOutputStream bytearrypacket = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    DataOutputStream dateoutputpacket = new DataOutputStream(bytearrypacket);
    dateoutputpacket.writeBytes("\r\n*KW\0");
    dateoutputpacket.writeShort(15);
    dateoutputpacket.writeShort(82);
    dateoutputpacket.writeByte(1);
    dateoutputpacket.writeBytes("\r\n");
    dateoutputpacket.flush();
    byte[] result = bytearrypacket.toByteArray();
```

Updated 2:

```
try {
                        ByteArrayOutputStream bytearrypacket = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        DataOutputStream dateoutputpacket = new DataOutputStream(bytearrypacket);
                        dateoutputpacket.writeBytes("\r\n*KW\0");
                        dateoutputpacket.writeShort(15);
                        dateoutputpacket.writeShort(82);
                        dateoutputpacket.writeByte(1);
                        dateoutputpacket.writeBytes("\r\n");
                        dateoutputpacket.flush();
                        byte[] result = bytearrypacket.toByteArray();
                        DatagramPacket responsepacket = new DatagramPacket(result, result.length, packet.getAddress(), packet.getPort());
                        dsocket.send(responsepacket);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (SecurityException se) {
                        se.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IllegalBlockingModeException il) {
                        il.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ilg) {
                        ilg.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Comment: Might sound like a obvious question but as this is a custom packet, is the length field in bits or bytes? i'm guessing bytes, but worth clarifying

Comment: The length field is there is bytes.

Comment: Total length of the packet I want to generate is 13 byte long

Answer (score 0):

Ive quickly put this together. Using this function you can create a byte array which has all packet information in the correct place. I used some of the sample info from the question. That should be enough to send the info across the connection. you can pass the byte array directly into your datagram

```
public class Sample {

public static void main(String[] args){

    byte[] packet = createMsg("\r\n*KW\0", (short)15, (short)82, '1', "\r\n");

    for(byte b : packet){
        System.out.println(b);
    }

}
public static byte[] createMsg(String sMark, short packetle, short cmd, char cErrorCode, String sEnd){
    byte[] buffer = new byte[13];

    char[] sMarkArr = sMark.toCharArray();
    char[] sEndArr = sEnd.toCharArray();

    // sMark
    buffer[0] = (byte) sMarkArr[0];
    buffer[1] = (byte) sMarkArr[1];
    buffer[2] = (byte) sMarkArr[2];
    buffer[3] = (byte) sMarkArr[3];
    buffer[4] = (byte) sMarkArr[4];
    buffer[5] = (byte) sMarkArr[5];

    // packetle
    buffer[6] = (byte)(packetle & 0xFF);
    buffer[7] = (byte)((packetle >> 8) & 0xFF);

    // cmd
    buffer[8] = (byte)(cmd & 0xFF);
    buffer[9] = (byte)((cmd >> 8) & 0xFF);

    // cErrorCode
    buffer[10] = (byte)(cErrorCode);

    // sEnd
    buffer[11] = (byte)sEndArr[0];
    buffer[12] = (byte)sEndArr[1];

    return buffer;
}
```

}

Remember when doing comms in java, the datatypes sizes and format aren't always the same as some other languages. 
Check out http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html to get each of the sizes

Hope this helps

EDIT:

Packet is 13 * 8  = 104 bits = 000000000000000000000000000000000000...

calling buffer[0] = (byte)sMark adds the char (e.g. A)

Packet is 13 * 8  = 104 bits = 001000001000000000000000000000000000...

calling buffer[6] = (byte)packetle adds the char (e.g. 2)

Packet is 13 * 8  = 104 bits =

[ Char 6 bytes                                      ][Short 1 byte]

[010000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000][00000010]...

NOTE: as you are using bytes for chars you will need to add an extra byte, as java chars are 16-bit, otherwise you may get loss of data

Comment: Here You have taken the first 6 byte into only one byte write ? how to make that into 6byte

Comment: What about buffer[1,2,3,4,5,7,9,12]?

Comment: Java char primatives are only 1 byte long, however the packet will be 000

Comment: You've missed out more than half of the packet data as defined by the OP's format. -1

Comment: Please Explain me How to write that.

Comment: You're dreaming. Assigning a byte to buffer[0] alters buffer[0] and nothing else. The remaining 4 bytes of 'sMark' are lost. And your API doesn't even accept them in the first place, as it is mis-designed to take a 'char' where it should take a 'char[]' or a String. @user3475175 Ignore this answer, it's just plain wrong.

Comment: @EJP please explain me, How could I able to create the packet.

Comment: yeah your correct, but as java char is only 1 byte in size your can't fill 6 bytes with 1 char ( http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html), sorry my bad 2byte

Comment: @PaulHickman Please explain how this method that only sets 5 bytes of a 13 byte message format can possibly be correct. You might also want to consider that GPS message formats probably weren't designed with Java data types in mind.

Comment: @user3475175 You could start by forgetting about this answer and looking at the other one.

Comment: because the packet size is fixed, and all un-altered bytes are 0. meaning that if your data only fits in 1-2 bytes, but your want a datagram to be bigger you can just leave them unaltered. Then it's up to the other side of the comms to decode the bytes based on the defined packet structure

Comment: You have completely ignored the length column. Have another look at the question. Please. Before you respond again.

Comment: @EJP could you please explain in which way I could able create packet.

Comment: @EJP please provide me the some document I will try.

Comment: @user3475175 I've provided my own answer. There's no sign that you've even seen it yet. Read it. If you have questions about it, ask them under that answer. Not here.

Comment: Ohhh you mean if the short is greater because it's 2 bytes, i see, i've edited it, but method still works the same, you just shift the short across, @EJP nice catch by the way

Comment: @PaulHickman Your latest edit still omits five bytes of the message, and puts the rest of it into little-endian order instead of network byte order.

Comment: the other bits are used only as padded and unless there is some really precise requirement about padding values, the default 0 should be fine. Also yeah you cant define the endian type until you know how the GPS reads it. @user3475175 this code isn't a copy and paste answer, the question depends to much on the other side of the communication, however you can use this stuff as an idea of how the packet is built up

Comment: @PaulHickman You are mistaken. All the bytes are significant. Read the question. There is no padding evident here. You're guessing. The 'sMark' field is defined as six bytes. Not one. It is customary if not universal in network protocols to use network byte order. That's why it's called that.

Comment: Now I am getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException .

Comment: @user3475175 For the *nth* time, *forget this answer.*

Comment: @PaulHickman Your latest late edit now fails to set bytes 2,3,4,5 of the message. This is getting pretty painful.

Comment: yeah because i'm leaving them as 0....whats the point of setting them to 0, you can add buffer[2] = 0; if it make you feel better, but it has no effect, the char can only be 2 bytes...so only use 2 bytes...4 bytes are padding

Comment: The field is defined as six bytes wide, with an example that is also six bytes wide. You need to read the question. Again. And again. And again. This is now completely ridiculous.

Comment: ohhhh I read the example as here are the valid characters, not this is a string of chars i wish to send, I'll modify the answer, also @user3475175 it would has been much easier from the start if you gave the example as a quoted string

Comment: @PaulHickman Easier why? He defined the field as six bytes long, in what looks like a quotation from the specification. He understood it, as you can see from his first comment. I understood it, ditto. The real problem here is that it has taken you two hours and a lot of coaching from the sidelines to read correctly something that was specified perfectly adequately in the first place. And re your latest edit, you were told most of that an hour ago. And you're still in little-endian order. And you're still doing it the hard way compared to using a DataOutputStream.

Comment: the first field has example (\r\n*KW\0) whereas the last field has "\r\n" so i see a difference, as they have different notation. It's also called Flag, not Flags so i assume only 1. I think thats a fairly easy mistake to make

Comment: I disagree. It's a perfectly normal way to document a protocol. You're just shooting the messenger here. It's not his fault, or mine, that you ignored an entire column for hours on end.

Answer (score 0):

Create a DataOutputStream around a ByteArrayOutputStream; use its various methods to write the data; then get the bytes from the ByteArrayOutputStream and wrap a DatagramPacket around that.

Comment: I had seen ur answer and I am trying also, please provide me some brief example.

Comment: I suggest you look up the Javadoc for DataOutputStream. It's clear enough. I would expect any professional programmer to be able to proceed from what's stated in this answer.

Comment: I am not understanding how to create that type of packet please expline me.

Comment: What *specific* part of my answer don't you understand?

Comment: In my question I have character like (\r\n*KW\0) I need to take individual separate or full car array

Comment: I have taken the like this  ByteArrayOutputStream bytearrypacket = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream dateoutputpacket = new DataOutputStream(bytearrypacket);

Comment: Very good. Now you need to do what I said an hour ago and use the various methods of DataOutputStream to write the various fields. I do expect you to look them up for yourself.

Comment: ByteArrayOutputStream bytearrypacket = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream dateoutputpacket = new DataOutputStream(bytearrypacket);
        dateoutputpacket.writeChars("\r\n*KW\0");
        dateoutputpacket.writeShort(15);
        dateoutputpacket.writeShort(82);
        dateoutputpacket.writeChar('1');
        dateoutputpacket.writeChars("\r\n");
        dateoutputpacket.flush();

        byte[] result = bytearrypacket.toByteArray();

Comment: You've done very well. What problem do you have now?

Comment: Problem is I have a packet length of 13 how i will not that in two byte?

Comment: I don't understand the question. You've done the right thing with the packet length, by writing it with writeShort(). What's the problem now?

Comment: When I iterate the array I am getting the length as 19 it has to come 13 right.

Comment: I between the character it is adding 0'

Comment: I think you need to use writeBytes() instead of writeChars(), after converting the Strings to bytes, as per your original code.

Comment: Also writeChar('1') should be writeByte(1).

Comment: I have update my code please see that,am I going proper? and it comes to the above format wht i need send.

Comment: Hi Shel i send the packet like this.

Comment: Looks good to me except for the 15. Shouldn't that be 13? And 82 should be 0x8200.

Comment: How I will get know whether this packet is set properly or not?

Comment: Err, did you consider looking at it to see what's inside? By printing it? Or using a debugger? Did you consider sending it anywhere? It's called debugging, and testing.

Comment: I have sent that packet to the gps device it sent but i am not understanding that it sent or not.